Awesome notification icon not showing
Hi i am using awesome notification to show notification so its working fine but showing white circle instead of app logo
i tried many ways
1.pass resource://drawable/ic_launcher_foreground
2.modify manifest file and more
but its not working
static Future<void> initialize() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
        null,
        [
          NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'high_importance_channel',
            channelName: 'Alerts',
            channelDescription: 'Alerts',
            playSound: true,
            defaultRingtoneType: DefaultRingtoneType.Notification,
            enableVibration: true,
            defaultColor: Colors.amber,
            enableLights: true,
            importance: NotificationImportance.High,
            defaultPrivacy: NotificationPrivacy.Private,
          )
        ],
        debug: false);
    initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications()
        .getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: false);
  }




create an icon in this route
android/app/src/main/res/drawable/your_icon_name.png

then edit your code to this
static Future<void> initialize() async {
    await AwesomeNotifications().initialize(
        "resource://drawable/your_icon_name",
        [
          NotificationChannel(
            channelKey: 'high_importance_channel',
            channelName: 'Alerts',
            channelDescription: 'Alerts',
            playSound: true,
            defaultRingtoneType: DefaultRingtoneType.Notification,
            enableVibration: true,
            defaultColor: Colors.amber,
            enableLights: true,
            importance: NotificationImportance.High,
            defaultPrivacy: NotificationPrivacy.Private,
          )
        ],
        debug: false);
    initialAction = await AwesomeNotifications()
        .getInitialNotificationAction(removeFromActionEvents: false);
  }

after do that restart your application

i tried but not working
